# Paypal Website Payments Pro recurring paymets via Paypal Express Checkout - How they notify us about next payment?

Tags: ruby, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

We have set up Website Payments Pro account and I managed to use ruby gem [paypal-recurring](https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring) to create initial payment and recurring profile.

But I still don't know few things and I can't find answer to some of them in API documentation (and/or on stack overflow).

- do they notify us via IPN that the next payment is billed?
- OR should I take granted that they bill the user every billing period automatically without any notification and I should rely on "cancel" IPN request (when the user cancels the payment on his/her paypal account)?
- OR I should be the one who will request next payment to users paypal account every billing period? (if this is the case, then I don't really get why I'm sending billing period to paypal when I'm creating recurring profile...)
- OR it works some other way?

Comment: So I've managed to prepare something to get it working... But I can't test it on the sandbox, as they don't send me the bill request via IPN every minute as they promise here https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id091EB080EYK . In fact, I receive only the initial payment request with status pending due to multiple currencies. The sandbox is set to GBP and I request the payment in GBP too (for this test) but it still complains about multiple currencies. So I don't get any other request after all. Just the initial one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do they notify us via IPN that the next payment is billed?

Exactly. You'll receive an IPN message each time a recurring payments profile is billed.
The main ID to refer to in each IPN message is the recurring_payment_id, which is the recurring payments profile ID which you got in response for calling the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API.

The IPN message will also include other data, such as the outstanding balance, next payment date, et cetera.
You can find a list of all included variables [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id091EB080EYK)

Comment: Thanks! Btw is it possible to test this in the sandbox somehow?

Comment: Ah, found answer to this (which also answers this question too :D ) https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide/testing_recurringpayments.html

Comment: it's been a while now, and no IPN request for recurring payment was made... (only those first ones for new customers)... I have to manually sync paypal emails (and transaction history) with our database. I don't know what I did wrong, but I can't find any solution to this...

Answer (score -1):

Simplify Integrations with Downloads and SDKs(paypal api)

Please refer [this](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks)